# Create a custom name for an address in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I'm reverse engineering a program using `gdb` and I'm getting confused in all the addresses I enter to various commands. Is there a way to create (and store) a custom variable so that I could say `x/i my_addr_name` instead of `x/i 0xdeadbeef`?

Comment: Would a [convenience variable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html) be what you need?

Comment: Convenience variables should be the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's probably it! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: could I also specify its size and have x/i 0xdeadbeff say `my_addr_name+16`?

Comment: Anyway, just post the answer and you'll get my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdb has user-definable [convenience variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html) to hold various values.

```
(gdb) set $my_addr_name=$pc
(gdb) x/i $my_addr_name
=> 0x400c7d <main+390>: lea    -0xa0(%rbp),%rax
(gdb) ptype $my_addr_name
type = void (*)()
```

Convenience variable have a type, and the `print` command will make use of that, but the `x` command uses explicit or default formats and doesn't take the type of the expression into account.

> could I have `x/i 0xdeadbeff` say `my_addr_name+16`

I don't think so, unless some additional C or python code is written. gdb's C source code has a [`build_address_symbolic`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=gdb/printcmd.c;hb=HEAD) function, which looks through the symbol tables to find the symbol nearest to an address. Short of creating a custom symbol table, then loading it with the `add-symbol-file` command, or writing a python extension to implement an alternative to the `x` command, I don't think such a customization is possible, currently.

Comment: Interesting. Could I write a plugin to this build_address_symbolic?